# Calling different Access Databases

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to come up with an interface to call the shortcut links of different Access Databases. On hand, I have the shortcut links (.lnk) of three (3) different databases (.mdb).

What is the most elegant and fastest way to do this? Should I create a form in Access to have 3 buttons with each function call pointing to open each shortcut link?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the FollowHyperLink method.